# Using pandas json_normalize to convert json into a dataframe, but some columns still have a list that I need to convert

Tags: python, json, pandas, list

I can successfully use pandas.io.json.json_normalize to convert my json object into the desired dataframe format. However, it seems some columns are not converted to the desired format within the dataframe, and are left as lists inside cell values.

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(res['transactions'])
```

Which will give me these df.columns

```
Index(['tradeID', 'tradeOpened.guaranteedExecutionFee',
       'tradeOpened.halfSpreadCost', 'tradeOpened.initialMarginRequired',
       'tradeOpened.price', 'tradeOpened.tradeID', 'tradeOpened.units',
       'tradesClosed'], dtype='object')
```

Note the columns such as 'tradeOpened.price' and 'tradeOpened.tradeID' are the desired target output and these seem to work ok. The problem is with the 'tradesClosed' column - I still get a column that contains cell values with a list inside of them that looks like this:

```
[{'tradeID': '2239', 'units': '-2838', 'realiz...
```

I want this to be broken up into columns like the tradeOpened was. So I should have columns like 'tradeClosed.tradeID' and 'tradeClosed.units'.

It seems a mutli step conversion process would be needed but I'm not sure the most effective way to go about this.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a pandas/json package efficient way but I wrote an iterator to update existing columns. (Some columns already existed from correct json transformation when the initial dataframe was created - but the other incorrect column contained data that needed to be added to these existing columns)

```
for idx in adf.index:

    tradeOpenedRow = adf['tradeOpened'][idx]

    if type(tradeOpenedRow) == dict:

        if type(adf.loc[idx,'tradeOpened.price']) == float:
            adf.loc[idx,'tradeOpened.price'] = tradeOpenedRow['price']

        if type(adf.loc[idx,'tradeOpened.tradeID']) == float: 
            adf.loc[idx,'tradeOpened.tradeID'] = tradeOpenedRow['tradeID']

        if type(adf.loc[idx,'tradeOpened.units']) == float:     
            adf.loc[idx,'tradeOpened.units'] = tradeOpenedRow['units']

        if type(adf.loc[idx,'tradeOpened.guaranteedExecutionFee']) == float:     
            adf.loc[idx,'tradeOpened.guaranteedExecutionFee'] = tradeOpenedRow['guaranteedExecutionFee']

        if type(adf.loc[idx,'tradeOpened.halfSpreadCost']) == float:     
            adf.loc[idx,'tradeOpened.halfSpreadCost'] = tradeOpenedRow['halfSpreadCost']

        if type(adf.loc[idx,'tradeOpened.initialMarginRequired']) == float:     
            adf.loc[idx,'tradeOpened.initialMarginRequired'] = tradeOpenedRow['initialMarginRequired']
            print('index ', idx, ' values set')
```